# Error when using ComBat

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm quite new to R and I'm trying to use the ComBat script in the R sva library on a 331 x 89 matrix of gene expression values. My data consists of 5 batches and it's ordered in that way so the first 106 rows correspond to batch 1, the next 106 correspond to batch 2 and so on.

```
 batch1 <- rep(1,times=106)
 batch2 <- rep(2,times=106)
 batch3 <- rep(3,times=39)
 batch4 <- rep(4,times=26)
 batch5 <- rep(5,times=54)
 batch.type <- as.factor(c(batch1,batch2,batch3,batch4,batch5))
```

Then I try to use ComBat using this command:

```
 ComBat(data,batch=batch.type,mod=NULL)
```

And I get the following readout and error message:

```
"Found 5 batches
Found 0  categorical covariate(s)
Standardizing Data across genes
Error in solve(t(design) %*% design) %*% t(design) %*% t(as.matrix(dat)) : 
  non-conformable arguments"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to run ComBat script from R's sva library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026331/unable-to-run-combat-script-from-rs-sva-library)

Comment: it's not a duplicate - the error message is different. There are no NAs in this data (the underlying problem in that thread)

Answer (score 11):

I've used ComBat in both the sva package (just this morning!) the InSilicoDb package ~ a year ago, and have gotten similar errors using the ComBat method in both packages. While there are other threads in a similar vein, the error messages can be different. I've encountered the "Error in solve(t(design) %*% design) %*% t(design) %*% t(as.matrix(dat)) : non-conformable arguments", and "Error in while (change > conv) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", in both cases when the variance across all my samples is not high enough.

The latter error is a bit more helpful:  you see intuit from "change" not being big enough that something's going on here with variance.  I often use a script I wrote to filter out very low-varying genes. Coefficient of variance is probably a better (standardized) metric, but if I threshold rather aggressively, to remove all genes below a variance of 1, ComBat then reliably runs (I just tried a lower threshold of .5 and it gave the error message you found. Probably a bit data-dependent also.)

Oddly enough, a stricter variance threshold has solved both of those error messages for me. I think it must do with how the code goes through iterating until convergence; perhaps low-varying genes can cause it to stop at a few points in the program?

A thread on the "change > conv" message is below. But removing only constant (variance =0) genes has never been sufficient enough for me to run ComBat like this user. His/her dataset must have had either variance = 0 or variance = a large number across all samples:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/combat-user-forum/_z8DxYQNFJ8/7UI_a2nCoUEJ

I don't love filtering out samples just because they're low-varying, but I haven't found a good method that can distinguish these from noise anyways.

Let me know if this helps - would be great to know if it's 100% due to low-varying genes (or whatever feature you have) across samples!

Comment: Removing just the zero variance features was enough for me -- but I appreciate your thoughtful answer.

Comment: I just ran on the same error. After trying a lot of thing in the direction of what @kplaney wrote, I noticed that the variance should be non 0 in all batches. ie for each genes, the batch specific variance of the measurement should be non 0.

Comment: @zetieum Good catch - I noticed same thing with current stable version of sva: filtered out genes with 0 variance for any batch fixed the issue. Fortunately it looks like it has been fixed though in the latest devel version of sva.

Answer (score 0):

I have found NA`s in my batch vector. Removing them helped me to go over the 'non-conformable arguments' error. And removing values with zero variance get me through the  "Error in while (change > conv) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" error.
check NA in the batch vector and 
add to your data matrix :

```
var.data <- apply(data, 1, var)
data <- data.free[-which(var.data == 0 ),]
```